# Jquery - Animation as Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello** I've simple animation car using HTML & CSS & JQuery but I'd like to add some effects, for example I need to stop car wheel rotation after the car come in and run the car wheel rotation when the car started to leave the screen, this was the first Problem.

### Second Problem

that I need when the car is come in screen change the car angle (rotate) and reduce the car speed.

and when the car is started to leave the screen, animation the car angle (rotate) and increase the car speed.

[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Nbm9D0ThEs&feature=youtu.be)

**Here my code:**

```js
$('.wheelEleContainer .slectWheel').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var getImgWheel = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.car .car__wheel').css('background-image',
      'url(' + getImgWheel + ')'
    );
});

var $cars = $('.car');
$('.car-model').on('click', function () {

    var $current = $cars.find('.current');
    var $next = $current.next();
    if ($next.length === 0) $next = $current.prevAll().last();

    $current.addClass('car--trans-out');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $current.removeClass('current').removeClass('car--trans-out');
        $next.addClass('current').addClass('car--trans-in');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $next.removeClass('car--trans-in');
        }, 1000)
    }, 1000);
})
```

```css
.car{
    height:600px;
    padding:40px 0;
    background-color:#efefef;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.car .click{
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #0094ff;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
.car-image-container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.current{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
.current .current{
    left: 0;
}

.car .car-image .car__wheel{
    width:99px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
}
.car .car-image .car__wheel.left{
    background-image:url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740531661.png');
    top:94px;
    left:98px;
}
.car .car-image .car__wheel.right{
    background-image:url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740544512.png');
    top:94px;
    right:75px;
}
.car--trans-in .car__wheel{
   animation: roll-in 400s ease-out;
}
.car--trans-out .car__wheel{
   animation: roll-out 400s ease-out;
}
.car--trans-in .car-image{
   animation: trans-in 1s ease-out;
}
.car--trans-out .car-image{
   animation: trans-out 1s ease-in;
}
.car--trans-in .car__wheel{
   animation: roll-in 1s ease-out;
}
.car--trans-out .car__wheel{
   animation: roll-out 1s ease-out;
}
.car--trans-in .car-image img{
   animation: bounce-in 1s ease-out;
}
.car--trans-out .car-image img{
   animation: bounce-out 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes trans-in {
    0% {transform: translateX(100%);}
    80% {transform: translateX(0%);}
    100% {transform: translateX(0%);}
}
@keyframes trans-out {
    0% {transform: translateX(0%);}
    10% {transform: translateX(0%);}
    80% {transform: translateX(-100%);}
    100% {transform: translateX(-100%);}
}
@keyframes roll-in {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    80% {transform: rotate(-720deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(-720deg);}
}
@keyframes roll-out {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(-720deg);}
}
@keyframes bounce-in {
    0% {transform: rotate(2deg);}
    70% {transform: rotate(2deg);}
    80% {transform: rotate(-1deg);}
    90% {transform: rotate(1deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
@keyframes bounce-out {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    20% {transform: rotate(2deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(2deg);}
}






.car .wheelEleContainer{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="car">
        <div class="container">
            <button>Next</button>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="car-button-container">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="click car-model" data-index="1">
                            Car Model 1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="click car-model" data-index="2">
                            Car Model 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="click car-model" data-index="3">
                            Car Model 3
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="click car-model" data-index="4">
                            Car Model 4
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="car-image-container current">
                        <div class="car-image" data-car-index="1">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727111161.png" alt="" />
                            <div class="car__wheel left"></div>
                            <div class="car__wheel right"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="car-image-container">
                        <div class="car-image" data-car-index="2">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727122822.png" alt="" />
                            <div class="car__wheel left"></div>
                            <div class="car__wheel right"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="car-image-container">
                        <div class="car-image" data-car-index="3">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727131353.png" alt="" />
                            <div class="car__wheel left"></div>
                            <div class="car__wheel right"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="car-image-container">
                        <div class="car-image" data-car-index="4">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992727151114.png" alt="" />
                            <div class="car__wheel left"></div>
                            <div class="car__wheel right"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="wheelEleContainer">
                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="slectWheel">
                            <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740561243.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <div class="slectWheel">
                            <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/14899275127831.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <div class="slectWheel">
                            <img src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/148992740580684.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Note:** please run code snippet in fullscreen

Comment: by rotating what do you mean? as rotating a 2D image viz of a *Car* is not good for visual exp.

Comment: watch my youtube video and you will understand what I mean :) thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CSS animations to get the car to transition into the frame, another animation to make the car rotate as it is moving.

Take a look at this example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ucmctrx/4/) I have done.

I am using a html structure like this:

```
<div class="cars">
    <div class="car">
        <div class="car__inner">
            <div class="car__chassis">
            </div>
            <div class="car__wheels">
                <div class="car__wheel car__wheel--left">
                </div>
                <div class="car__wheel car__wheel--right">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Using jQuery I am adding some classes to the `<div class="car">` which will allow us to attach CSS animations.

```
var $cars = $('.cars');
$('button').on('click', function(){

  var $active = $cars.find('.car--active');
  var $next = $active.next();
  if($next.length===0) $next = $active.prevAll().last();

  $active.addClass('car--trans-out');
  setTimeout(function(){
    /*Wait a second before removing the class*/
    $active.removeClass('car--active').removeClass('car--trans-out');
    $next.addClass('car--active').addClass('car--trans-in');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $next.removeClass('car--trans-in');
    },1000)
  },1000);
})
```

Edit: Here is another [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ydsacuo/1/) which is using the same markup and script as the original post with the addition of some class names and animations

Comment: Thank you for your answer I need to Stop Car Wheel When the car come in, and Please apply your code in my Example until I can understand

Comment: @MohamedHassn I have update the fiddle above to include the wheels spinning

Comment: Thank you it's work well so I will try it on my codes, Thank again and kindly regards

Comment: I'm Sorry But it's not work well in my code Please forgive me could you edit your code to compatible with my snippet.

Comment: Hey Please if you could help me

Comment: Thank you very much you are helpful man, I edit my code snippet Please show it, that I need when click on car modal 1 animation car 1 ..etc

Comment: Take a look at this updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ydsacuo/1/)